# How WeakReference is affecting working of this program

Tags: java, dictionary, reference, weak-references

Why below System.exit(0) is called in below program? It should be called only when map reference variable becomes null.

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference; 
import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.util.Map; 
public class ReferencesTest { 
    private WeakReference<Map<Integer, String>> myMap; 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        new ReferencesTest().doFunction(); 
    } 

    private void doFunction() { 
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>(); 
        myMap = new WeakReference<Map<Integer, String>>(map); 
        int i = 0; 
        while (true) { 
            if (myMap != null && myMap.get() != null) { 
                myMap.get().put(i++, "test" + i);
                System.out.println("im still working!!!!"+i+" Map Size"+myMap.get().size()); 
                System.gc();
            } else { 
                System.out 
                .println("*******im free*******"); 
                System.exit(0);
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Last few lines of Output are

```
im still working!!!!15586 Map Size15586
im still working!!!!15587 Map Size15587
im still working!!!!15588 Map Size15588
*******im free*******
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

THE VARIABLE `map` is not used (not referenced) anywhere inside the `while` cycle (or further down). Just because the variable is still in scope, as seen in source; or the fact that it does have a designated local variable entry in the method's bytecode does not mean that THE VARIABLE `map` is actually in scope DURING RUNTIME, especially after JIT compilation.

Unless you compile with an option to explicitly keep unused local variables (in their whole scope), this is the expected behavior.

Proof (`--XX:+PrintCompilation`):

```
im still working!!!!15586 Map Size15586
im still working!!!!15587 Map Size15587
im still working!!!!15588 Map Size15588
 259509   23 %           eu.revengineer.sync.ReferencesTest::doFunction @ -2 (144 bytes)   made not entrant
*******im free*******
```

Comment: But it is weakly referenced by myMap which is still in use.

Comment: A weak reference is completely disregarded by the GC. That's what 'weak' means, after all.

Comment: You are not using (the variable) `map`. `myMap` is a weak reference; yes, `myMap.get()` does return the same object that the variable `map` was initialized with, but it has nothing to do with (the variable) `map`.

Comment: @afk5min ok lets say "map is not used anywhere inside the while cycle" then still I did not make it null , why it got garbage collected ?

Comment: First of all, if you change your code to `System.out.println("*******im free*******" + map);`. You will notice that your loop does no longer stop. There might be two possibilities: JIT (`-XX:+PrintCompilation`) or GC (heap limit reached, test with low heap, such as `-Xmx4M`)

Comment: The cause was related to the Hotspot Just-in-time compiler. See the answer.

Comment: @afk5min , if it is because of Just-in-time compiler isn't it bad ? if we use WeakHashMap in this way it will never work. If I want to use this map for caching purpose I can loose my whole map.

Comment: I got it now , if I want to use map for caching I should not use map as local variable because it becomes eligible for garbage collection due to JIT compiler, If I use map as instance variable it works fine. Thanks @afk5min for perfect explanation. I was not aware JIT can do such things :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you actually want to use is the WeakHashMap (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html).

A weak reference to a HashMap will be removed under memory pressure, rendering your whole map unreachable and even terminating the program in your case. WeakHashMap uses weak references to its keys instead so only the map will lose (key, value) pairs under memory pressure.

Comment: actually I was wondering why my code is not working , there is something I am missing here so need help in this particular example.

Comment: What is your code trying to achieve? Shall it survive when requesting more and more memory? Then the question is what you are going to throw away if the resource is becoming scarce. If it is entries of the map, I'd consider reading about WeakHashMap or a real caching solution.